# How to add an invisible ViewModel to the Navigation Stack in MvvmCross

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have the following app situation.
At startup I want to go to the "List"ViewModel as a startup viewmodel/view.
But I want the user to be able to choose BACK to goto the "Menu"ViewModel.
How would this be done in MvvmCross?

Comment: Your Acception Rate is quite low and regarding Stuart excellent answer here, you should accept it.

Answer (score 5):

If you ever want to support WP7, then that navigation will struggle to get through the marketplace submission process - the back flow is sacred on wp7.

That flow also doesn't make that much sense for Android or iPhone users either... so you might be better considering an alternative UX flow - you can still have the flow ListView->Menu->... but you can avoid "BACK" syntax that users understand as BACK.

---

I think I'd implement this type of UX as:

On startup navigate to the ListView/ListViewModel normally.

Present some way - a menu, button, or hyperlink - to let the user to navigate to HomeView/HomeViewModel - but try to use a "home" or "menu" metaphor rather than a "back" one - "back means back" especially on WP7.

In the navigation to Home, set the flag for "ClearTop" in the navigation - e.g.:

```
public IMvxCommand GoHomeCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new MvxRelayCommand(RequestNavigate<HomeViewModel>(true));
    }
}
```

This "ClearTop" flag will be interpreted by iOS and WP7 to clear the navigation back stack once you reach Home. However, sadly it doesn't currently work perfectly in Android - so you'll need to do something clever in your Android UI project - e.g. maybe somehow find a way to use the "NoHistory" flag for the special start ListView/Activity.

---

Interested to hear if there are other ways of doing this.