# MonoDroid MVVMCross handle back button pressed on a TabHost

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am using the MvvmCross framework to build a cross platform (iOS, Android, WP7) application. I am currently trying to handle the back button pressed on Android from a TabHost Activity. The TabHost Activity will have been started from another Activity(that isn't in the Tab selection) and I want the back button to close the application, however when the back button is pressed I am returning to the previous screen.

The 'NoHistory = "true"' doesn't seem to work within the TabHost.

I am handling my back button press in the View as below but aren't sure what can be called in the ViewModel to close the application.

```
public override bool OnKeyDown(Android.Views.Keycode keyCode, Android.Views.KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (keyCode == Keycode.Back)
        {

            return this.ViewModel.CloseThisApplication();

        }
        return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
    }
```

Are there any methods that can be called to close the application? Or have a better idea on how this may be handled? Ideally the method could be replicated across the three platforms specified earlier.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think we can replicate an exitNowPlease call across all 3 platforms - as most of them discourage you from supplying an Exit feature - e.g. I believe the only way to exit in WindowsPhone7 is to throw an unhandled exception.

However, I think you should be able to achieve what you describe  by:

1. add the NoHistory=true flag to the start activity - the one before the tabhost. This `NoHistory=true` flag means don't include this activity type in the back stack.
2. remove your back button handler.

The platform should then behave as you've described.

---

Also for cross platform clearing the back stack, see the ClearTop explanation in [How to add an invisible ViewModel to the Navigation Stack in MvvmCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246013/how-to-add-an-invisible-viewmodel-to-the-navigation-stack-in-mvvmcross)

Comment: That's great, although in some situations I am going to need to catch the back button and overload its method to an IMvxCommand.
Is there any way of binding the back button in the XML to one of these commands? Rather than catching it myself and calling a method in the ViewModel?

Comment: I tried the ["How to add an invisible ViewModel to the Navigation Stack in MvvmCross"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246013/how-to-add-an-invisible-viewmodel-to-the-navigation-stack-in-mvvmcross) but it the doesn't allow me to go to the previous page.

Comment: I'm sure you could add something, but sound like maybe this is something that should be handled in codebehind

Comment: for extended chat, try http://jabbr.net/#/rooms/mvvmcross For questions like "I tried .. but it the doesn't..." try writing out a new question in full with code explaining what you are talking about (that comment was too brief for me to understand exactly what you have done) - also best to try a few things yourself before posting a question - and often writing a question can lead to a moment of revelation (it often does for me anyway!)